# Начало работы с OpenGL на андроиде

Tags: android, java, opengl

В классе, наследуемом от Render, я определяю метод. Он должен устанавливать ортографическую проекцию и вьюпорт.

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl, 0, 0, width, height);
}
```

И рисую две точки с координатами (0, 0) и (-1, 0). Приложил картинку результата.

[image]

Если честно, то я ожидал, что нарисуеться одна точка в углу. Т.к предполагаю, что центр будет в углу, а размеры будут совпадать с разрешением экрана. В openGL я не силен, мб кто-нибудь объяснит что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(0,0) в таком раскладе будет как раз в центре кадра. Так что, очевидно, что всё нарисовалось верно. Я бы вам посоветовал начать с OpenGL просто на большом ПК. Для него и примеров много и возможностей для тестов больше. Это поможет вам понять, как OpenGL, и вообще 3D графика "работает".

**UPD** К сожалению, мне не совсем понятно, чего вы пытались добиться и мне не ясно, что с вашей точки зрения правильно. Вы уверены, что вам нужно именно ортогональное проецирование? Я так подозреваю, что вы хотите сдвинуть 0,0 в левый верхник край, тогда вам придётся добавить к матрице трансформации ещё и нужный сдвиг. Вообще-то, это несколько противоестесственно, но вполле возможно.

Причиной, по которой для вас расположение (0,0,0) по центру кажется неожиданным, является незнание основ OpenGL. Стоит прочесть пару статей аля-Hello World по теме.

Следующий пример нарисует горизонтальные линии от середины к краям влдоль осей x и y (по цвету вершины можно говорить о направлении: от красного к зелёному, от красного к синему). Я использую JOGL на большом ПК, так как прямо сейчас нет под рукой машины с Android SDK:

```
        public void display(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable) {
            GL gl = glAutoDrawable.getGL();
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();

            gl.glBegin(GL.GL_LINES);
                gl.glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
                gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);

                gl.glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
                gl.glVertex3f(1, 0, 0);

                gl.glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
                gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);

                gl.glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
                gl.glVertex3f(0, 1, 0);
            gl.glEnd();
        }

        public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int i, int i1, int w, int h) {
            GL gl = drawable.getGL();

            gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();

            gl.glOrtho(0, 0, w, h, 1, -1);
        }
```

[image]

Но стоит добавить трансформацию..

```
         public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int i, int i1, int w, int h) {
            GL gl = drawable.getGL();
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();

            gl.glOrtho(0, 0, w, h, 1, -1);
            gl.glScalef(1, -1, 1);
        }
```

[image: Повёрнуто]

И, наконец подвинем влево вверх

```
         public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int i, int i1, int w, int h) {
            GL gl = drawable.getGL();
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();

            gl.glOrtho(0, 0, w, h, 1, -1);
            gl.glTranslatef(-1, 1, 0);
            gl.glScalef(1, -1, 1);

            gl.glTranslatef(0.01f, 0, 0);
        }
```

Внимание: последний gl.glTranslatef(0.01f, 0, 0); был добавлен для того, чтобы левая синяя ось не уходила за пределы экрана.. просто чтобы чуть-чуть подвинуть всё вдоль оси X:

[image: Подвинуто и повёрнуто]

**UPD2**
Ну, разумется функции glOrtho и gluOrtho2D не принимают экранные координаты на вход. Прочтите хотя бы документацию по ним: [glOrtho](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glOrtho.xml)  и [gluOrtho2D](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluOrtho2D.xml). Вообще, надо привыкнуть что функции glXXX почти никогда не принимают никакие экранные координаты. Даже те, которые принимают на вход два параметра. Исключений очень мало.. на ум приходят только glViewport и glReadPixels*

Comment: А может вы мне посоветуете как правильно включить ортографическую проекцию?

Comment: Спасибо за разьяснение, оно натолкнуло меня на правильный ответ. 
glOrtho и gluOrtho2D в качестве параметров принимают не координаты левого нижнего и правого верхнего угла, а координаты плоскостей отсечения. И правильный вариант    

 GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl, 0, width, 0, height);
 gl.glOrtho(0, w, 0, h, 1, -1);

После этого центр будет в левом нижнем углу.